# Automatically closing ('OK'-ing) a Windows Script Host dialogue box from a batch script

Tags: batch-file, popups, deactivation

I have an incredibly annoying problem where my Win 10 license keeps randomly deactivating for no reason. Sometimes it lasts weeks without doing it but recently it seems to be doing it every other day. I've tried all available fixes I can find but none of them stick and eventually Windows deactivates itself again at some point (I do have a genuine valid retail license).

To fix it is easy but annoying: all I need to do is open Windows Settings>Activation and click on the Troubleshoot link and it immediately activates itself.

To make it even easier I've written a one line batch script that also activates it immediately and pinned it to my taskbar:

```
slmgr /ato
```

This works fine and I just click the script icon and it runs but also leaves a 'Windows Script Host' confirmation pop-up box on screen that I have to OK out of. Is there an easy (or easier) way to automatically close it as part of the script?

Sorry, I know nothing about coding but just want the quickest way to zap it when it happens (I know getting to the root of the deactivation problem would be better but I've tried everything I can find and just want it to go away in the least number of steps!)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you know it, as soon as I post this question I get an idea of how to Google it and found the answer of adding '//b' to the script like this so it runs in batch mode (with no output):

```
slmgr /ato //b
```

Works fine and I might just autorun it when Windows boots to pre-empt it as it seems to be deactivating nearly every time I boot up recently.

Comment: Why not just fix windows by repairing it. In all the time I used Windows 10 it did not lose activation.